# Valid REGEX for CHECK constraint?

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
CONSTRAINT proper_nccondutor CHECK (nccondutor ~ '[a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

When I try to insert:

```
insert into condutor (idpessoa,nccondutor, dtnascimento)
values (2,'BD-1231234' ,'1998-03-09');
```

it gives this error:

> SQL Error [2201B]: ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character range

Is the regex invalid? I want a `nccondutor` like for eg."AZ-1234567".

Comment: The range `[a-Za-Z]` makes no sense. Do you maybe mean `[a-zA-Z]`? Also the range `[-]` is not valid, did you maybe mean `-`?

Answer (score 2):

If you dump your current regex into a demo tool ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/6FEwqK/1)), you will notice that the character ranges are out of order.  These are the problem:

```
[a-Za-Z]
```

You should be phrasing as this:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

You could also use a case insensitive regex in Postgres, and tighten up to this:

```sql
CONSTRAINT proper_nccondutor CHECK (nccondutor ~* '^[a-z]{2}-[0-9]{7}$')
```

The above assumes that you intend the pattern to be a full match, which seems to be the case.